# Mapbox GL Feature Manipulation

Tags: mapbox-gl

Running  "mapbox-gl": "^0.53.1"

I want to update the color of a layer "type": "fill-extrusion"
This is not just one feature that I select, but it might be a multitude of features that are altered (otherwise this [highlight feature with click in mapbox gl](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186533/highlight-feature-with-click-in-mapbox-gl) solution might work). but adding a new layer is therefore not an option. This is what I tried - it obviously does not work.

```
this.map.on('click', 'grid-test', function (e) {
      e.features[0].properties["color"] = "#ff00ff";
});
```

I have not found propper update methods that I can call to tell a layer to rerender. The other solution I see is to reset all the data - but I am still a bit reluctant to that solution. Coming from an OL background, I expect certain basic functions to exist.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is change the color of one layer, you can use something like this [exmaple](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/color-switcher/):

```
map.on('click', 'grid-test',function (e) {
  map.setPaintProperty( 'grid-test', 'fill-extrusion-color', "#ff00ff");
});
```

I would recommend adding a variable to test whether it has been clicked or not, so you decide when you want to change the color, checkout the example, maybe add a button that does that, or add another listener on the rest of the map that sets the layer back yo its original color.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a new layer, my solution is to reset the clicked layers data like this:

```
let clickedLayer: GeoJSONSource =  map.getSource('grid-test') as GeoJSONSource;
let currentSource = clickedLayer['_data'];
for (let feature of currentSource["features"]) {
  if (feature.properties["id"] === clickedFeature.properties["id"] || feature.properties["id"] === 0) {
    feature.properties["color"] = "#ff00ff";
  }
}
clickedLayer.setData(currentSource);
```